# Ruby: console.log?

Tags: ruby

I recently put console.log statements in every line of a JavaScript program and found that it's now much easier to understand.  Is there a way to do that with server side code, specifically Ruby?  I presume there's no way to read it in firebug, but would it be visible in irb? what console.log equivalent statements would I put in the Ruby code?

Comment: By the way, `console.log` isn't supposed to be used in *every line of a JavaScript program*. That's dirty as hell and will make important messages (exceptions, JS errors, HTTP errors, etc.) harder to see.

Comment: I'm sure that's a useful way to learn how to code though.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

`puts` is the equivalent in ruby.

Example

```
puts 'Hello World!'
```

Comment: so puts doesn't interfere with the rest of the program in anyway?  do I have to put anything in brackets?

Comment: No brackets required :) `puts` will print and continue on so `puts a` will print the variable `a` just like `console.log(a)` would. In Ruby parenthesis are not required, so `puts(a)` is the same as `puts a`.

Comment: I think the more sort of equivalent of `console.log(a)` would be `puts a.inspect` or `p a` shortcut. (for example `puts [1, 2, 3]` will print 1, 2 and 3 in separate lines while `p [1, 2, 3]` and `console.log([1, 2, 3]))` will give `[1, 2, 3]` giving the structure of the object.

Comment: There are a lot of gems to make puts output nicer, like prettyprint

Answer (score 12):

If you are running your server in the console, you can use `puts`. Otherwise, you will need to write to a file, possibly via a logger (like `Rails.logger.info`).

Comment: can you show me how to do it? with console.log, I just put the code to be logged inside the parentheses? console.log(model.get(id) and that keeps the code separate from the rest of the program. How does puts know to keep it separate from the rest of the program

Comment: So I don't know what you mean by "seperate" a print in both Javascript and Ruby are a sequential operation performed before they move on. As you can see in my comment above `puts a` on a line by itself will print the variable `a`. `puts` can be used just like `console.log`

Comment: The equivalent code to what you have, in ruby would be `puts model.id`

Comment: OP said a Ruby equivalent **not** a Rails one. You should take a look at the [Ruby's logger](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html) instead of Rails one because Ruby Logger is included in the StdLib since Ruby 2.1.0

Comment: Ruby's `puts` method is the closest equivalent of JS's `console.log` when the stdout of the server is somewhere accessible which is the first sentence of my answer. Ruby's logger class adds a bunch of useful functionality, but it is not the equivalent of `console.log`. Writing to a file can be achieved by using the same method on an open file object with `File#puts`.